# Biber can't find bib file

Tags: biber, biblatex-chicago, bibdesk, texpad

I hope you're all well. I'm having some confounding difficulty with incorporating a bibliography into my MA thesis. I'm using Texpad & BibDesk on a Mac. I have the following lines in my tex file:

```
\usepackage[authordate, backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{thesis.bib}
```

It looks like this *should* work, as Texpad pulls up the document in the "Structure" panel, and is able to identify the items contained therein. However, when I run LaTeX, I get the message:

```
Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                thesis
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

Looking at the blg file, I see:

```
[317] Biber.pm:4523> INFO - Looking for bibtex format file ''/Users/bob/Documents/Cal/Thesis/Thesis Text/thesis.bib'' for section 0
[466] Utils.pm:411> ERROR - Cannot find ''/Users/bob/Documents/Cal/Thesis/Thesis Text/thesis.bib''!
[467] Biber.pm:132> INFO - ERRORS: 1
```

Yet thesis.bib *is* at that location! I can open it with BibDesk and Texpad. I've tried running Biber from the command line and I get:

```
INFO - This is Biber 2.15
INFO - Logfile is 'thesis.bib.blg'
ERROR - Cannot find 'thesis.bib.bcf'!
INFO - ERRORS: 1
```

I can't think what to do next to try to solve this.

Comment: Just grasping for ideas: Sometimes, various executable programs in the TeX distribution get thrown off by whitespace in folder names in the path. Could you try to rename the folder `Thesis Text` to, say, `ThesisText`, reload TeXpad, and rerun pdflatex and biber?

Comment: Thanks! I gave that a shot, but, alas, no dice.

Comment: Thanks. Next idea: the line `INFO - Logfile is 'thesis.bib.blg'` shows that something very odd is going on: If the main tex file is called `thesis.tex`, the bibliography log file should be called `thesis.blg`, *not* `thesis.bib.blg`. How exactly do you run `biber`?

Comment: Normally from within Texpad. There's the call:

\usepackage[authordate, backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{thesis.bib}

in the preamble to my thesis. This *was* working until today. I've since tried it from the command line.

Comment: Can you open a terminal window, navigate to `/Users/bob/Documents/Cal/Thesis/Thesis Text/` (or maybe `/Users/bob/Documents/Cal/Thesis/ThesisText/` by now...), delete all aux files (mainly the ones that end in aux, log, bbl, blg) by hand, and run by hand `pdflatex thesis`, `biber thesis`, and `pdflatex thesis` one more time?

Comment: It was xetex rather thatn pdflatex, but that worked! Thanks so much!

Comment: Glad my hunch was productive. :-) In the longer run, though, you should investigate further what may have gone astray in TeXpad's settings.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.

Comment: This seems like an important, relevant question about Latex that will help others. Shouldn't we leave the question open so that someone is incentivized (reputation points) to turn these comments into a compact answer?